# Is an inner select from the same table more efficient from "regular" select

Tags: sql, select

I can't find any answer that talks about the efficient side (which query is running faster, not how to write the query!). I appreciate your help in this matter.

is this query better (and run faster then):

```
SELECT c.user_id_1 
FROM (
  SELECT b.user_id_1, b.mail_id 
  from table_name as b where name='test
) as a where a.age ='18') as c
```

this query:

```
select user_id_1 from table_name
where name='test
and age ='18'
```

Both of the queries gives me the same results. but can I test which query is faster?

Comment: Any decent optimizer will run both in the same way. But to find out, just check the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html)

Answer (score 1):

I can think of no database where using a subquery would be faster.  In most databases, the two queries would produce exactly the same execution plan -- regardless of indexes, partitions, and other factors.

It is important to understand that SQL engines do not directly execute a SQL statement.  They convert the SQL statement into a directed acyclic graph (DAG) that looks (to the uninitiated) nothing like the original statement.  Part of this process is optimizing the code, which makes the execution graph even less like the original code.

Some versions of MySQL and MariaDB have a habit of materializing subqueries in the `FROM` clause.  This can have a deleterious effect on performance!  So, a subquery can sometimes make things much worse.

It is also possible that very complex subqueries might confuse the optimizer, but a simple case such as yours would not be one of those cases.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this was just an example of a query. the query that I'm trying to run is much more complicated and contains 5 inner select in it (from the same table!).
That what I thought the inner selection can make things worse, but I couldn't find any information on it.

Answer (score 1):

I just tested this on a table with 13,745,928 records. If both user_id and age are covered with a clustered index then both queries will produce the same plan using a Clustered Index Seek with a Cost 100%. In this case, both queries returned in under 5 seconds.

On a side note: If you have **multiple** subqueries that return data from the same table(s) then it may be more performant to build up an indexed #temptable to replace the subqueries or CTEs. When you use the same subquery more than once, the query analyzer will return a plan for each subquery, meaning each subquery will be executed, not just one.